# Plotlegend in Mathematica does not work for a table of functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I am trying to plot a list of functions with a legend using PlotLegend in Mathematica v8.  As a simple test illustrating what I'm trying to do.

```
<<PlotLegends`
test = Table[f[x], {f, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Log, Exp}}]
Plot[test, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, Axes -> {True, False}, 
PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
PlotLegend -> {"Sin", "Cos", "Tan", "Log", "Exp"}, 
LegendPosition -> {0, -0.5}, LegendShadow -> None]
```

Gives as output

```
{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Log[x], E^x}
```

[image: Incorrect Legend]

However, if I explicitly put the table in the Plot command, I get the correct legend.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Log[x], Exp[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> Full, Axes -> {True, False}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
PlotLegend -> {"Sin", "Cos", "Tan", "Log", "Exp"}, 
LegendPosition -> {0, -0.5}, LegendShadow -> None]
```

[image: Correct Legend]

For my actual application, I'm putting together a list of functions within a Do loop, so the latter Plot command is not ideal.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Does `Plot[Evaluate@test, ...]` help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `Plot[test, ...]` with `Plot[Evaluate@test, ...]`.

The problem is that Plot takes the first argument unevaluated and only evaluates it when calculating points. Therefore when it determines the labels, it only sees a single argument `test`, not a list, and therefore it only outputs one label. `Evaluate@test` tells Mathematica to evaluate `test` before passing it to `Plot` even though `Plot` is defined to take the argument unevaluated. This way, Plot sees the list you stored in `test` and knows to generate several labels.